# How to have multiple classes share pointers to a common class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, design-patterns

I'm trying to determine the right approach to a design issue, but I am struggling to find something 'right'.

In simple terms:

- I have multiple functional classes that each need to interact with multiple common classes. (all created on the heap with New)

Eg

```
A class [a] object needs to be able to call methods in class [x], [y] & [z] objects
A class [b] object needs to be able to call methods in class [x], [y] & [z] objects
A class [c] object needs to be able to call methods in class [x], [y] & [z] objects
```

I have 3 solutions so far:

1. Make the common classes (x, y, z) global objects (or a singletons) so the functional classes (a, b, c) can just call the objects directly. However, I dislike the idea of making things global.
2. Pass pointers to the common classes (x, y, z) to each of the functional classes (a, b, c) during initialisation for later use. However, if a common class is deleted, the functional classes have stale pointers.
3. Have a single global object (perhaps a singleton) that 'manages' the common classes (x, y, z), and the functional classes (a, b, c) request a common class pointer as/when needed from this global object. This allows them to know if the pointer is NULL immediately.

Previously, I've used (2), but over time I've become unhappy with this approach.

I think I'm currently favouring (3) but still uncomfortable with having a global object/singleton.

I've been searching around for a design pattern that fits this kind of scenario, but can't find anything that fits, maybe due to not knowing the right keywords.

Is there a common design approach/pattern to this problem?

Comment: Maybe you should read about [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)?

Comment: Any reason you can't do (2) and then (by design) ensure that you dispose of a, b and c before x, y and z?

Comment: It is not possible to give a recommendation when the problem driving the design pattern to use is unknown.

Comment: You speak of classes when you really should speak of objects ! Nothing will never delete a class, and a class is never *created on heap*, only objects are. But as you contemplate using singletons or global objects, could you just use static methods (and fields) of a real class - ie no object creation ?

Comment: can't you pass the objects x,y,z as parameters of the functions you are calling in a,b,c?

Comment: Why might a common class be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to provide a recommendation without seeing more specifics of the problem but based on what you have said I would go with option 2.

If the lifetimes are properly managed, preferably using RAII and resource managing objects, there is no reason for the common classes to be deleted until the functional classes are deleted.

You say all classes are created on the heap with `new` but you can use something like `std::unique_ptr` to manage the lifetime:

```
#include <memory>

struct X { };
struct Y { };
struct Z { };

class A {
    X* x_;
    Y* y_;
    Z* z_;
  public:
    A(X* x, Y* y, Z* z) : x_(x), y_(y), z_(z) { } 
    void doSomething() { /* use x_, y_ and z_ ... */ }
};

// Similarly for B and C ...

int main() {
    auto x = std::make_unique<X>();
    auto y = std::make_unique<Y>();
    auto z = std::make_unique<Z>();

    auto a = std::make_unique<A>(x.get(), y.get(), z.get());
    a->doSomething();
}
```

If `x`,`y` and `z` are always used together or should be created lazily you could go with something like option 3 and combine them into one "managing" object but I would avoid making that managing object global/singleton if you can and just pass it by reference or pointer into the initialization of the functional classes, as in option 2:

```
struct XYZ {
  std::unique_ptr<X> x;
  std::unique_ptr<Y> y;
  std::unique_ptr<Z> z;
  XYZ():x(std::make_unique<X>()), y(std::make_unique<Y>()), z(std::make_unique<Z>()){}
};

class A {
    XYZ* xyz_;
  public:
    A(XYZ* xyz) : xyz_(xyz) { } 
    void doSomething() { /* use xyz_ ... */ }
};

// Similarly for B and C ...

int main() {
    XYZ xyz;
    auto a = std::make_unique<A>(&xyz);
    a->doSomething();
}
```